# Generate a Sound file with a 15Khz tone

Tags: python, c, audio, mp3

I'm playing around with high-pitched sounds. I'd like to generate an MP3 file with a 1 second 15Khz burst. Is there a simple way to do this from C or Python? I don't want to use MATLAB.

Comment: Keep in mind that a tone of 15KHz can have many shapes, i.e. sine, square, triangle, sawtooth, etc.

Comment: I would be really interested in a solution, which generates the mp3 directly. Creating some wave file and compress it with lame is a quite obvious but boring solution. Some small C prog which generates a mp3 with a tone (15kHz or whatever) which can be played by any decoder would be awesome. Any mp3-file geeks here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use Python's [`wave`](http://docs.python.org/library/wave) module to create a wave file which you could then compress to MP3. To create a one second 15khz sine wave:

```
import math
import wave
import struct

nchannels = 1
sampwidth = 2
framerate = 44100
nframes = 44100
comptype = "NONE"
compname = "not compressed"
amplitude = 4000
frequency = 15000

wav_file = wave.open('15khz_sine.wav', 'w')
wav_file.setparams((nchannels, sampwidth, framerate, nframes, comptype, compname))
for i in xrange(nframes):
    sample = math.sin(2*math.pi*frequency*(float(i)/framerate))*amplitude/2
    wav_file.writeframes(struct.pack('h', sample))
wav_file.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

I would break this into 2 pieces:

1. Create a wave file using a C++ library(like [libsndfile](http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/) library)
2. Convert the wave file to mp3 using a utility (like [lame](http://lame.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/lame/lame/doc/html/switchs.html#t)). This is a command line tool which can be called from your C program as well. see `-t` for converting wave to mp3.

One thing to note is 15KHz is very high frequency to be heard by human and I guess most of speakers are not capable of playing it as it is beyond cutoff frequency of them. So don't be surprised if you don't hear the result.

Comment: +1, but about the speaker range, many headphones have response frequencies of up to 20,000Hz. Whether or not you can hear it is a different story!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
#include<dos.h>
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
    sound(500); // Frequency
    delay(1000); // Time
    nosound(); // Stop
}
```

Comment: That library is such a blast from the past, but what platforms does it run on today?

Comment: How is this upvoted? Not only antiquated C practices (implicit return values), but platform-specific when no platform specified in tags or question... Also has nothing to do with generating MP3s.